# Sentence generator with words from lists using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

So I'm trying to learn python, and I have written this code that's supposed to generate sentences from lists of random words and random numbers, I've started with this code but I'm not sure if it's gonna work

Here is my code:

```
import random

num = random.randrange(0, 9)
drug = ['Advil', 'Synthroid', 'Crestor', 'Nexium', 'Vyvanse', 'Lyrica']
form = ['capsule', 'tablet', 'Powder', 'gel', 'liquid solution', 'Eye drops']

lines = []
for item in drug, form:
    line = '- the patient was prescribed [' + num + '](dosage) [' + item.form + '](form) of [' + item.drug + '] for [' + num + 'days](Duration)
    lines.append(line)
```

This is the results I'm expecting :

```
[the patient was prescribed [1](Dosage) [capsule](Form) of [Advil](Drug) for [5 days](Duration),
the patient was prescribed [2](Dosage) [Powder](Form) of [Nexium](Drug) for [6 days](Duration),
the patient was prescribed [5](Dosage) [luiquid solution](Form) of [Vyvanse](Drug) for [4 days](Duration),
...]
```

Comment: what is medicaments here in your code ?

Comment: i meant ''for item in drug, form:''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do it

```py
import random

## generate 6 random numbers
nums = [random.randrange(0, 9) for _ in range(6)] 
days = nums = [random.randrange(0, 9) for _ in range(6)]
drugs = ['Advil', 'Synthroid', 'Crestor', 'Nexium', 'Vyvanse', 'Lyrica']
forms = ['capsule', 'tablet', 'Powder', 'gel', 'liquid solution', 'Eye drops']

lines = []
## zip will take one element from each array at one time
for num, drug, form, day in zip(nums, drugs, forms, days):
    ## this is string formatting syntax in python you put your local 
    ## variable inside curly brackets
    line = F"- the patient was prescribed {num} dosage {form} of {drug} for {day} days"
    lines.append(line)

print(lines)
```